# Run .exe from a python script called by mercurial in cmd shell

Tags: python, mercurial, cmd, executable

I have tied a python (2.7) script to a commit in mercurial. In this script, a .exe is called (via the subprocess module), which has previously been generated via the cx_freeze. This .exe basically opens a cmd prompt for receiving user inputs.

When I run a commit through the hg workbench, everything works as intended... the Python script runs, calls the executable, and does its stuff, and the commit works without a hitch.

However, when running a commit via  "hg commit" in an initial cmd prompt, the executable portion of this setup never appears. I know the python script still runs.  No errors are ever displayed/returned.

Am I missing something obvious, and is there a simple way to get this executable to run properly even when called from a commit in cmd prompt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have mercurial calling a hook that runs a python script that launches an executable that is a python script compiled to an exe?  Likely the 3-layer deep script is being run w/o a "terminal" (headless), but it sounds like if you un-snarled a few of those layers you might be better off.

Comment: I would rather not remove layers due to the fact that a few thousand lines of code will have to be ported, including modules (as the executable was compiled with a different version of Python.) You were right about the script running headless, so I suppose I'm hoping for a way to get the script to run with its own terminal.

Comment: Yeah, you're into windows-specific tricks there then.  You could try having the hook be a batch or powershell script and see if there's a way you can get that to launch the exe with a controlling terminal, but otherwise I'm of no help. :(